# Adding of filled circles to PDF page using Apache PDFBox

Tags: java, pdf, drawing, pdfbox

I'm trying to use the [Apache PDFBox](https://pdfbox.apache.org/) library to create a PDF document programmatically. The class [PDPageContentStream](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.13/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/edit/PDPageContentStream.html) contains methods to write text, draw lines, bezier curves, rectangles. But I can't find a way to draw a simple filled circle. Is there a way to draw it using this library? If not, can you please suggest a free Java library that provides flexible API to create PDF documents programmatically? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Mostly duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781610/how-to-draw-a-pie-chart-in-pdfbox/ PDF does not have an operator for circles, you have to approximate it with Bezier curves.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr how do you fill in the area circumscribed by 4 bezier curves? I've run into this exact problem and had to use annotations to get around it

Comment: @mstorkson After drawing your shape with appropriate bezier curves you call fill().

Comment: @mstorkson And of course you have to set a non stroking color.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr well the application is in people's hands already, but good to know for the future.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, thanks everyone for responses. I like the solution with bezier curves. This approach works for me:

```
private void drawCircle(PDPageContentStream contentStream, int cx, int cy, int r, int red, int green, int blue) throws IOException {
    final float k = 0.552284749831f;
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(red, green, blue);
    contentStream.moveTo(cx - r, cy);
    contentStream.curveTo(cx - r, cy + k * r, cx - k * r, cy + r, cx, cy + r);
    contentStream.curveTo(cx + k * r, cy + r, cx + r, cy + k * r, cx + r, cy);
    contentStream.curveTo(cx + r, cy - k * r, cx + k * r, cy - r, cx, cy - r);
    contentStream.curveTo(cx - k * r, cy - r, cx - r, cy - k * r, cx - r, cy);
    contentStream.fill();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

So, I ran into this problem, and there is a way, but its kind of cheaty and depending on what you want to do, not a good solution. You can take advantage of PDF "annotations" which include a circle type, for example:

```
PDAnnotationSquareCircle circle = new PDAnnotationSquareCircle(PDAnnotationSquareCircle.SUB_TYPE_CIRCLE);
PDRectangle position = new PDRectangle();
position.setLowerLeftX(0);
position.setLowerLeftY(0;
position.setUpperRightX(100);
position.setUpperRightY(100);
circle.setRectangle(position);
```

and then call

`circle.SetInteriorColor(someCOSColor);`

with a color as the argument to fill it. The problem with this, is that its an "annotation" unless you lock the document for being edited, people can drag them around. Also, if people on Windows try to print them, they will not see the annotations. Use at your own risk, but it will give you filled colored circles

Edit: added a more complete example in response to a comment

Comment: That is an annotation. It isn't what the OP asked for.

Comment: "But I can't find a way to draw a simple filled circle." is the quote from the question. This will create a filled circle on his document. I think I explained the drawbacks adequately. Actually, if there is another way to do it, I would be interested in hearing about it, because I used that in an application and it is causing the issues I described.