# Drawing pie chart with PDFbox

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I'm trying to draw Pie chart with PDFbox, but there are white lines between the slices, could anyone help me with this? is there an option for this?

Attached the code for drawing the arc that I'm using:

```
while (start < stop) {
    List<Float> smallArc = PdfUtils.createSmallArc(a, b, radius, start, start + 
        2.0944 > stop ? stop : start + 2.0944);
    contentStream.saveGraphicsState();
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(components[0], components[1], 
        components[2]);
    contentStream.moveTo(smallArc.get(0), smallArc.get(1));
    contentStream.curveTo(smallArc.get(2), smallArc.get(3), smallArc.get(4), 
        smallArc.get(5), smallArc.get(6), smallArc.get(7));
    contentStream.fill();
    contentStream.restoreGraphicsState();
    start += 2.0944;
}


public static List<Float> createSmallArc(float x, float y, double r, double a1, double a2) {
    double a = (a2 - a1) / 2;
    double x4 = r * Math.cos(a);
    double y4 = r * Math.sin(a);
    double x1 = x4;
    double y1 = -y4;
    double q1 = x1 * x1 + y1 * y1;

    double q2 = q1 + x1 * x4 + y1 * y4;
    double k2 = 4 / 3d * (Math.sqrt(2 * q1 * q2) - q2) / (x1 * y4 - y1 * x4);
    double x2 = x1 - k2 * y1;
    double y2 = y1 + k2 * x1;
    double x3 = x2;
    double y3 = -y2;

    double ar = a + a1;
    double cos_ar = Math.cos(ar);
    double sin_ar = Math.sin(ar);

    List<Float> list = new ArrayList<Float>();
    list.add((float) (r * Math.cos(a1)) + x);
    list.add((float) -(r * Math.sin(a1)) + y);
    list.add((float) (x2 * cos_ar - y2 * sin_ar) + x);
    list.add((float) -(x2 * sin_ar + y2 * cos_ar) + y);
    list.add((float) (x3 * cos_ar - y3 * sin_ar) + x);
    list.add((float) -(x3 * sin_ar + y3 * cos_ar) + y);
    list.add((float) (r * Math.cos(a2)) + x);
    list.add((float) -(r * Math.sin(a2)) + y);
    return list;
}
```

Attached image of the result:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: try strokeAndFill, and set the stroking color to the same as the non stroking color. What do you get?

Comment: `start` and `stop` are not changed in your code, so once in that `while` loop, your program will never leave it until some error occurs...

Comment: @mkl
I edited the question and added the missing code.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr
The issue is fixed thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `fill()`, use the `fillAndStroke()` method and call `setStrokingColor()` with the same parameters that you used for `setNonStrokingColor()`.